# How to convert raw data of mpu6050 to control mouse cursor?

Tags: java, arduino, mouse, mpu6050

I have a project to complete which is about " Controlling PC mouse cursor using sensor " in which I have to use Java, Arduino and MPU-6050 as sensor.

I planned to use the code of below for mouse cursor movement

```
public void moveRight() throws AWTException {
  PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
  Point b = a.getLocation();
  int x = (int) b.getX();
  int y = (int) b.getY();
  Robot r = new Robot();
  r.mouseMove(x+10, y );}
```

i plan to create moveRight(),moveLeft()moveUP(),moveDown() functions for mouse cursor movement . this function will be call upon on base of MPU-6050 sensor moving .

but I have no idea how to convert raw data of MPU-6050 to usable data for cursor movement.

Answer (score 0):

`MPU6050` has a accelerometer and a gyroscope (also a temperature sensor). What you need is the orientation of the device and to get this you could calculate the `Euler` angles. 
MPU6050 throws in raw accelerometer and gyro values that you must convert to `Euler angles` which can be send over any serial bus to your PC. The rest your Java code will take care.

**How to get started**
1. Use an arduino library to fetch the raw readings
 [Here](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050) and [here](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050) (this is a famous and well written library) 
2. Use a complementary filter (use [Madgwick](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/MadgwickAHRS)'s, you just need acc and gyro) to "sensor fuse" (google: sensor fusion) the two readings to calculate the yaw, pitch, roll (euler angles). These are your orientation in a 3D plane.  
3. Pass on these calculations to the PC where you can assign the mouse behavior according to the orientation. Like higher speed of movement for the mouse pointer if we have a higher inclination.

**Why all the trouble?**
Your application needs to control the mouse by lets say how you move your hand. We could have calculated the angle of inclination using just accelerometer readings but your hand is not a stationary object and can influence the sensor to have more than "acceleration due to gravity". 
So it's recommended you use a complementary filter (or a Extended Kalman, it.s a good read, but maybe a overkill for your application) to calculate the angles.

Each of the repos I've linked have example code and resources to help you get started. Good luck!